# Magmi Run Import issue on prod server

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I am unable to do import using Magmi on production server. This is working properly on localhost. I don't know why it won't or recognize the magmi engine.

here is my

```
Warning: require_once(var/www/vhosts/inkfast.com.au/shop.inkfast.com.au/magmi-importer/inc/magmi_engine
.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/inkfast.com.au/shop.inkfast
.com.au/magmi-importer/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 16

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'var/www/vhosts/inkfast.com.au/shop.inkfast.com
.au/magmi-importer/inc/magmi_engine.php' (include_path='.::/var/www/vhosts/inkfast.com.au/shop.inkfast
.com.au/magmi-importer/inc:/var/www/vhosts/inkfast.com.au/shop.inkfast.com.au/magmi-importer/integration
/inc:/var/www/vhosts/inkfast.com.au/shop.inkfast.com.au/magmi-importer/engines') in /var/www/vhosts/inkfast
.com.au/shop.inkfast.com.au/magmi-importer/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 16
```

Comment: The error clearly says that the file magmi_engine.php is failed to load. Check the file is exists and file permission.

Comment: yep it exists and I've made the whole folder 777 to just to be able to have a sample run

Comment: Have you configured magmi with the right base folder?

Comment: I tried the original MAGMI and it's working properly. this is an issue with the MAGMI where they modified the User Interface